# Arrays.parallelSort vs Collections.sort

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I was checking a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210530/comprator-sorting-one-object-always-on-top) that wanted to know how to use `Comparator` and a **Orange** fruit to be first all the time. From the post toString method was missing so I added to my code

```
@Override
public String toString(){
    return fruitName +"  " + fruitDesc;
}
```

The given answer to the post was

**use Collection.sort**

```
Collections.sort(fruits, new Comparator<Fruit>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Fruit o1, Fruit o2) {
            if (o1.getFruitName() != null && o1.getFruitName().equalsIgnoreCase("orange")){
                return -1;
            }

            if (o2.getFruitName() != null && o2.getFruitName().equalsIgnoreCase("orange")){
                return 1;
            }

            return o1.getFruitName().compareTo(o2.getFruitName());
        }
    });
```

**output**:

```
Orange  Orange description
Apple  Apple description
Banana  Banana description
Pineapple  Pineapple description
```

I was thinking why not  `Arrays.parallelSort` which I have been told good stuff about

[read more here](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/04/arrays-sort-versus-arrays-parallelsort.html)

**using `Arrays.parallelSort` code**

```
 Fruit[] arrayFruits = fruits.stream().toArray(Fruit[]::new);
 Arrays.parallelSort(arrayFruits, (Fruit o1, Fruit o2) -> {
     if (o1.getFruitName() != null && o1.getFruitName().equalsIgnoreCase("orange")){
         return -1;
     }
     if (o2.getFruitName() != null && o2.getFruitName().equalsIgnoreCase("orange")){
         return 1;
     }
      return o1.getFruitName().compareTo(o2.getFruitName());
    });
```

**output**:

```
Pineapple  Pineapple description
Apple  Apple description
Orange  Orange description
Banana  Banana description
```

[The link to the post is here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26210530/comprator-sorting-one-object-always-on-top)

**To me sorting is sorting, why different answer form different method ?**

Comment: does these [link1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17328077/difference-between-arrays-sort-and-arrays-parallelsort) and [link2](http://java.dzone.com/articles/arrayssort-versus) help you.

Comment: @ankur-singhal thank you but I have checked already

Comment: @KickButtowski: Are you sure you ran the program correctly. Regardless of the order in which I enter the values, `Orange` is placed first.

Comment: @Ya I am sure did you see the post

Comment: Same for me: cannot reproduce it. Orange comes first.

Comment: how do you try to printout the list?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If one runs the program in [**TryJava8**](http://www.tryjava8.com/app/snippets/54323a0ce4b0347a1a361266), I get the correctly sorted array. I think you probably printed the input (`fruits`) instead of the output (`arrayFruits`). This said, you opened an interesting topic, since in general, you are right a sorting algorithm does not guarantee the full order. In general for large arrays, if two elements are equivalent, but not the same (for instance a different pointer to an equivalent record), the algorithms do not guarantee a specific order. This said ties are in general broken differently by different algorithms.

A compare method should satisfy the **order relation constraints**:

An order relation should be:

- reflexive: every item should be equal to itself (you better return `0` I guess)
- asymmetrical: if *A* is less than or equal to *B* and *B* is less than or equal to *A*, *A* and *B* are equal.
- transitive: if *A* is less than or equal to *B* and *B* is less than or equal to *C*, *A* is less than or equal to *C*.

Most of the sorting algorithms assume this constraints implicitly (they don't check them) and thus offer a *O(n log n)* time complexity. If the condition does not hold, depending on the implementation of the algorithm, one obtains different results.

Since a parallel sort uses the `MergeSort` algorithm, and a default sort uses the `QuickSort` algorithm, the two algorithms have different behavior.

A relevant topic: most sorting algorithms are not stable. Say two items are "equal", then it is not guaranteed that if *A* was placed before *A'* in the original array, *A* will be placed before *A'* in the resulting array.

Comment: the outcome must be the same. based on the post, the orange has to be first all the time

Comment: All right, but note that for large arrays, items that are "equivalent" (but not the same, for instance a different pointer) can be shuffled...

Comment: The “default” does *not* use `QuickSort` as `QuickSort` is not a stable algorithm and `Collections.sort` is guaranteed to be stable. `QuickSort` might be used where the stability of the sorting is meaningless, e.g. when sorting numbers like `Arrays.sort(int[])` does. It’s worth noting that the comparator of the question does violate the contract of `Comparator` as it doesn’t handle the case that both elements have the name `"orange"` correctly.